# __thiscall already defined in .obj

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, stl, linker

I am getting linker errors which I cannot seem to find the root cause of, having checked for including .cpp files and reading other forums.

The errors are:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Penguin_RPG, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\users\adam\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\penguin_rpg\penguin_rpg\dialogue.hpp(53): warning C4018: '<=' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\adam\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\penguin_rpg\penguin_rpg\main.cpp(39): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Area::Area(class Dialogue,class Inventory,class std::vector<class Creature *,class std::allocator<class Creature *> >)" (??0Area@@QAE@VDialogue@@VInventory@@V?$vector@PAVCreature@@V?$allocator@PAVCreature@@@std@@@std@@@Z) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Creature::Creature(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,int,int,int,int,double,unsigned int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (??0Creature@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@HHHHNI0@Z) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Creature::Creature(void)" (??0Creature@@QAE@XZ) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Dialogue::Dialogue(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::vector<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > >)" (??0Dialogue@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@2@@Z) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Item::Item(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (??0Item@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0@Z) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Weapon::Weapon(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,unsigned int,double)" (??0Weapon@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0IN@Z) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Dialogue::activate(void)" (?activate@Dialogue@@QAEHXZ) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Inventory::add_armour(class Armour *,int)" (?add_armour@Inventory@@QAEXPAVArmour@@H@Z) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Inventory::add_item(class Item *,int)" (?add_item@Inventory@@QAEXPAVItem@@H@Z) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Inventory::add_weapon(class Weapon *,int)" (?add_weapon@Inventory@@QAEXPAVWeapon@@H@Z) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Inventory::clear(void)" (?clear@Inventory@@QAEXXZ) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Creature::equipArmour(class Armour *)" (?equipArmour@Creature@@QAEXPAVArmour@@@Z) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Creature::equipWeapon(class Weapon *)" (?equipWeapon@Creature@@QAEXPAVWeapon@@@Z) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: unsigned int __thiscall Creature::expToLevel(unsigned int)" (?expToLevel@Creature@@QAEII@Z) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: bool __thiscall Creature::levelUp(void)" (?levelUp@Creature@@QAE_NXZ) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Inventory::merge(class Inventory *)" (?merge@Inventory@@QAEXPAV1@@Z) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Inventory::print(bool)" (?print@Inventory@@QAEX_N@Z) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Inventory::print_armours(bool)" (?print_armours@Inventory@@QAEH_N@Z) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Inventory::print_items(bool)" (?print_items@Inventory@@QAEH_N@Z) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Inventory::print_weapons(bool)" (?print_weapons@Inventory@@QAEH_N@Z) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Inventory::remove_armour(class Armour *,int)" (?remove_armour@Inventory@@QAEXPAVArmour@@H@Z) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Inventory::remove_item(class Item *,int)" (?remove_item@Inventory@@QAEXPAVItem@@H@Z) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Inventory::remove_weapon(class Weapon *,int)" (?remove_weapon@Inventory@@QAEXPAVWeapon@@H@Z) already defined in atlas.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Area::search(class Creature &)" (?search@Area@@QAEXAAVCreature@@@Z) already defined in atlas.obj
1>C:\Users\Adam\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Penguin_RPG\Debug\Penguin_RPG.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

atlas.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef ATLAS_HPP
#define ATLAS_HPP

#include <vector>

#include "creature.hpp"
#include "item.hpp"
#include "weapon.hpp"
#include "armour.hpp"
#include "area.hpp"

//atlas building functions. Atlases contain vectors of
//game data that is not modified. Could be replaced with
//functions that read from config files.

void buildatlas_creature(std::vector<Creature>& atlas);
void buildatlas_item(std::vector<Item>& atlas);
void buildatlas_weapon(std::vector<Weapon>& atlas);
void buildatlas_armours(std::vector<Armour>& atlas);
void buildatlas_area(std::vector<Area>& atlas,
    std::vector<Item>& items, std::vector<Weapon>& weapons,
    std::vector<Armour>& armours, std::vector<Creature>& creatures);

#endif //ATLAS_HPP
```

atlas.cpp:

```
#include "atlas.hpp"

void buildatlas_creature(std::vector<Creature>& atlas)
{
    //fill the atlas
    //Creature(name, health, str, end, dex, hitRate, level)
    atlas.push_back(Creature("Rat", 8, 8, 8, 12, 2.0, 1));

    return;
}
void buildatlas_item(std::vector<Item>& atlas)
{
    //Item(name, description)
    atlas.push_back(Item("Gold Coin", 
        "A small disc made of lustrous metal"));
    atlas.push_back(Item("Iron Key",
        "A heavy iron key with a simple cut"));

    return;
}
void buildatlas_weapon(std::vector<Weapon>& atlas)
{
    //Weapon(name, description, damage, hitRate)
    atlas.push_back(Weapon("Iron Dagger", 
        "A short blade made of iron with a leather hilt",
        5, 10.0));
    atlas.push_back(Weapon("Excalibur",
        "The legendary blade, bestowed upon you by the lady of the lake",
        35, 35.0));

    return;
}
void buildatlas_armours(std::vector<Armour>& atlas)
{
    //Armour(name, description, defence, slot)
    atlas.push_back(Armour("Leather Vest",
        "Torso armour made of tanned hide",
        4, Armour::Slot::TORSO));

    return;
}
void buildatlas_area(std::vector<Area>& atlas,
    std::vector<Item>& items, std::vector<Weapon>& weapons,
    std::vector<Armour>& armours, std::vector<Creature>& creatures)
{
    // Area definitions are somewhat more complicated:
    atlas.push_back(Area(Dialogue(        // Standard dialogue definiton
        "You are in room 1",              // Description
        { "Go to room 2", "Search" }),      // Choices
        Inventory(                        // Area inventory
    {
        std::make_pair(&items[0], 5)  // Pair of item and quantity

    },
    {
        std::make_pair(&weapons[0], 1)// Pair of weapon and quantity
    },
    {
        std::make_pair(&armours[0], 1) // Pair of armour and quantity
    }),
    {                                 // Creatures
    }));

    atlas.push_back(Area(Dialogue(
        "You are in room 2",
        { "Go to room 1", "Search" }),
        Inventory(
    {
        std::make_pair(&items[0], 10),
        std::make_pair(&items[1], 1)
    },
    {
    },
    {
    }),
    {
        &creatures[0]
    }));

    return;
}
```

inventory.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef INVENTORY_HPP
#define INVENTORY_HPP

#include "item.hpp"
#include "weapon.hpp"
#include "armour.hpp"

#include <list>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

class Inventory
{
public:
    //Whilst weapons and armour are items, they have their own 
    //specific properties and can't be stored in the same list.
    //The first element of the pair stores a pointer to the item
    //in the item/weapon/armour atlas, defined in main(), the second
    //if the quantity of the item

    std::list<std::pair<Item*, int>> items;
    std::list<std::pair<Weapon*, int>> weapons;
    std::list<std::pair<Armour*, int>> armours;

    Inventory(){};
    Inventory(std::list<std::pair<Item*, int>> items,
        std::list<std::pair<Weapon*, int>> weapons,
        std::list<std::pair<Armour*, int>> armours)
    {
        this->items = items;
        this->weapons = weapons;
        this->armours = armours;
    }

    void add_item(Item* item, int count);
    void add_weapon(Weapon* weapon, int count);
    void add_armour(Armour* armour, int count);

    void remove_item(Item*, int count);
    void remove_weapon(Weapon*, int count);
    void remove_armour(Armour*, int count);

    void merge(Inventory* inventory);
    void clear();

    int print_items(bool label);
    int print_weapons(bool label);
    int print_armours(bool label);
    void print(bool label);
};

//add an item to the inventory
void Inventory::add_item(Item* item, int count)
{
    // Increase the quantity if the item already exists
    for (auto& it : this->items)
    {
        if (it.first == item) it.second += count;
        return;
    }
    // If the item doesn't already exist in the inventory, then a
    // pair must be created too
    this->items.push_back(std::make_pair(item, count));
}
void Inventory::add_weapon(Weapon* weapon, int count)
{
    for (auto& it : this->weapons)
    {
        if (it.first == weapon)
        {
            it.second += count;
            return;
        }
    }
    this->weapons.push_back(std::make_pair(weapon, count));
}

void Inventory::add_armour(Armour* armour, int count)
{
    for (auto& it : this->armours)
    {
        if (it.first == armour)
        {
            it.second += count;
            return;
        }
    }
    this->armours.push_back(std::make_pair(armour, count));
}

void Inventory::remove_item(Item* item, int count)
{
    // Iterate through the items, and if they are found then decrease
    // the quantity by the quantity removed
    for (auto& it : this->items)
    {
        if (it.first == item) it.second -= count;
    }
    // Iterate through the list again, and remove any elements from
    // the list that have zero or less for their quantity
    // We do this in two passes because removing an element from
    // a list during a for loop invalidates the iterators, and the
    // loop stops working
    this->items.remove_if([](std::pair<Item*, int>& element)
    {
        return element.second < 1;
    });
}

void Inventory::remove_weapon(Weapon* weapon, int count)
{
    for (auto& it : this->weapons)
    {
        if (it.first == weapon) it.second -= count;
    }
    this->weapons.remove_if([](std::pair<Weapon*, int>& element)
    {
        return element.second < 1;
    });
}

void Inventory::remove_armour(Armour* armour, int count)
{
    for (auto& it : this->armours)
    {
        if (it.first == armour) it.second -= count;
    }
    this->armours.remove_if([](std::pair<Armour*, int>& element)
    {
        return element.second < 1;
    });
}

//merge the specified Inventory with the current one
//adding item quantaties if they exist, creating a new slot if they don't
void Inventory::merge(Inventory* inventory)
{
    // You can't merge an inventory with itself!
    if (inventory == this) return;

    // Loop through the items to be added, and add them. Our addition
    // function will take care of everything else for us
    for (auto it : inventory->items)
    {
        this->add_item(it.first, it.second);
    }
    // Do the same for the weapons
    for (auto it : inventory->weapons)
    {
        this->add_weapon(it.first, it.second);
    }
    // Do the same for the armour
    for (auto it : inventory->armours)
    {
        this->add_armour(it.first, it.second);
    }

    return;
}

void Inventory::clear()
{
    this->items.clear();
    this->weapons.clear();
    this->armours.clear();
}

//output a list of items to stdout, nicely formatted
int Inventory::print_items(bool label = false)
{
    unsigned int i = 1;

    for(std::list<std::pair<Item*, int>>::iterator it =
        this->items.begin(); it != this->items.end(); ++it)
    {
        //number items if asked
        if(label)
        {
            std::cout << i++ << ":";
            //output the item name, quantity and description
            std::cout << it->first->name << " (" << it->second << ") - ";
            std::cout <<it->first->description << std::endl;
        }
    }
    //return number of items outputted, for convienience
    return this->items.size();
}

//output a list of weapons to stdout, nicely formatted
int Inventory::print_weapons(bool label = false)
{
    unsigned int i = 1;

    for (auto it : this->weapons)
    {
        if (label) std::cout << i++ << ": ";
        std::cout << it.first->name << " (" << it.second << ") - ";
        std::cout << it.first->description << std::endl;
    }

    return this->weapons.size();
}

//output a list of armour to stdout, nicely formatted
int Inventory::print_armours(bool label = false)
{
    unsigned int i = 1;

    for(std::list<std::pair<Armour*, int>>::iterator it =
        this->armours.begin(); it != this->armours.end(); ++it)
    {
        //number items if asked
        if(label)
        {
            std::cout << i++ << ":";
            //output the item name, quantity and description
            std::cout << it->first->name << " (" << it->second << ") - ";
            std::cout <<it->first->description << std::endl;
        }
    }
    //return number of items outputted, for convienience
    return this->armours.size();
}

//print the entire inventory, unless it is empty
void Inventory::print(bool label = false)
{
    if(this->items.size() == 0 && 
        this->weapons.size() == 0 &&
        this->armours.size() == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Empty!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        this->print_items(label);
        this->print_weapons(label);
        this->print_armours(label);
    }
    return;
}
#endif //INVENTORY_HPP
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

#include "area.hpp"
#include "armour.hpp"
#include "atlas.hpp"
#include "creature.hpp"
#include "dialogue.hpp"
#include "inventory.hpp"
#include "item.hpp"
#include "weapon.hpp"

Creature dialogue_newChar();

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<Creature> creatureAtlas;
    std::vector<Item> itemAtlas;
    std::vector<Weapon> weaponAtlas;
    std::vector<Armour> armourAtlas;
    std::vector<Area> areaAtlas;

    // Build the atlases
    buildatlas_creature(creatureAtlas);
    buildatlas_item(itemAtlas);
    buildatlas_weapon(weaponAtlas);
    buildatlas_armours(armourAtlas);
    buildatlas_area(areaAtlas, itemAtlas, weaponAtlas,
        armourAtlas, creatureAtlas);

    Creature player;

    //seed rand() with system time, to produce better random numbers
    srand(time(NULL));

    //main game menu dialogue
    int result = Dialogue("Welcome to the jungle!", { "New Game" }).activate();

    switch (result)
    {
    case 1:
        player = dialogue_newChar();
        break;
    default:
        return 0;
        break;
    }
    // Set the current area to be the first area in the atlas,
    // essentially placing the player there upon game start
    Area* currentArea = &(areaAtlas[0]);

    // Play the game until a function breaks the loop and closes it
    while (1)
    {
        // If the player has died then inform them as such and close
        // the program
        if (player.health <= 0)
        {
            std::cout << "\t----YOU DIED----\n    Game Over\n";
            return 0;
        }

        // Activate the current area's dialogue
        result = currentArea->dialogue.activate();

        // These could be moved inside of the area code using an
        // event style system, but that allows for much less
        // flexibility with what happens in each area. Since we're
        // defining the areas in code anyway, sticking with this
        // isn't too much of a problem, and it keeps things easy
        // to understand
        if (currentArea == &(areaAtlas[0]))
        {
            switch (result)
            {
            case 1:
                // Move to area 1
                currentArea = &(areaAtlas[1]);
                break;
            case 2:
                // Search the area
                currentArea->search(player);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (currentArea == &(areaAtlas[1]))
        {
            switch (result)
            {
                // Move to area 0
            case 1:
                currentArea = &(areaAtlas[0]);
                break;
                // Search the area
            case 2:
                currentArea->search(player);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;

}

//create a new character
Creature dialogue_newChar()
{
    //ask for a name and class
    std::cout << "Choose your name punk!" << std::endl;
    std::string name;
    std::cin >> name;

    int result = Dialogue("Choose your class!", { "Fighter", "Rogue" }).activate();

    switch (result)
    {
    case 1:
        //Fighter favours health and strength
        return Creature(name, 35, 20, 10, 5, 10.0, 1, "Fighter");
        break;
    case 2:
        //Rogue favours endurance and dexterity
        return Creature(name, 30, 5, 10, 20, 15.0, 1, "Rogue");
        break;
    default:
        //default should not happen, good to be safe though!
        return Creature(name, 30, 10, 10, 10, 10.0, 1, "Adventurer");
        break;
    }
}
```

I can add the code for additional files if needed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the implementation of the Inventory class methods to a .cpp file.

What's happening is that the header file is included in a few differnt .cpp files, so thise methods are compiled in several differnt compilation units. This causes the that linking error that says those methids already exist in a differnt compilation unit.

In fact all implementations except template implemtations should exist in their own .cpp files, exactly for that reason.

Comment: Ah that makes sense! I have moved the inventory class methods to a .cpp file and the linker errors have disappeard. Now to fix the rest of the program! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

When you define member functions, you have the following choices to prevent multiple definitions:

1. Put them in the `.cpp` files not in the `.hpp` files like you have some of them now. This is the most preferred.
2. Put them inline in the class body. Good for one-liners in some cases.
3. Put them outside the class body but mark them with the `inline` keyword.

Right now you have member functions defined outside the class body in header files and not marked with `inline`. I would recommend you do #1 and move those to the `.cpp` files instead.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occures when you try to include single `inventory.hpp` file with class `Inventory` methods implementation to different `.cpp` (`main.cpp` and `atlas.cpp` via `atlas.hpp`) files. 
If you will separate interface and implementation of the class `Inventory`, then it will resolve your problem.

Separation is also important because

1. You hide implementation, so client code have to use an object through its public interface
2. It reduces building time of your project
3. You can change implementation `.cpp` file without changing interface file `.hpp`

More about separating you can read in article [Separating Interface and Implementation in C++](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/269)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. Then I realized I had multiple declarations to the .h file in separate .cpp files. This fixed the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple declarations to the .h file "? How realizing something could possibly solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

```
#include "*.hpp"
```

will define your methods multiple times. Make a `*.h` file, declare all methods there and use

```
#include "*.h"
```

Define your methods in a `*.cpp` file.